# Why did Adam kill her?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark

In Dark series Season 3, we see that Hannah travels back to 1911, to Adam (Jonas, his son) alongside Silja who is his half-sister. Adam tells them that they are in "wrong place". So at midnight, Adam sneaks into Hannah and Silja's room to take Silja and send her to post-apocalypse time. But Hannah wakes up and after a little chat with Adam (which is not aggressive), Adam suffocates and kills her, his mother!

Was it necessary to kill her? Although she is secretly a cunning, selfish and ruthless individual, she happens to care about Jonas and throughout the story we don't see a clue that Jonas is upset about her actions. Jonas is a powerful man in 1911 and definitely Hannah can't stop him to do his job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By that time, in 1911, all the years of working with the time machine has caused Jonas physical and mental change. He's become cold, calculating, and vengeful. Magnus tells Hannah that Jonas is not the same thanks to all the time travel.

> He has changed. Traveling has left its mark on him.

Hannah announces to Adam that she was approached by an Old lady who advised her to go to 1911, Eva.

> A few days ago there was this old woman. She just showed up on our
> doorstep. Eva. She said she knew where you were. And that you were
> looking for me.

Adam instantly considers this to be a threat to his plans. Something that Eva is doing to disrupt his scheme to destroy the knot.

Considering Hannah has the potential to disrupt, and that he has lost all worldly affections, Adam simply chooses to eliminate Hannah to ensure his plan is not disturbed. It's like swatting a fly for him.

(Little does he know that Eva is a step ahead of him all the time)

Answer (score 1):

Adam killed Hannah because he needed to kidnap Hannah’s daughter Silja in order to move her to the right time to ensure events play out as they always have.  In particular she needs to be in the post-Apocalypse future and then she needs to go to the past in order to have children with Bartosz.

Answer (score -3):

Silja, Adams half sister has a scar across her face. Very much like the scar that Martha is given by her older self.
I assumed the scar indicates this child is from Eva's world, not Adams world.

This would still leave a lot of questions unanswered: Why does Hannah not have the same cut? What happened to Hannah from Adam's world? Why only kill Hannah but not Silja?

Comment: Silja (in the future of Adam's world) has the same scar. We know that she is the same person who eventually goes to the past to meet and be with Bartosz. Both worlds _must_ have Silja as she is Noah's and Agnes' mother. There is no indication in the series that a scar means it's a person from Eve's world (other than Martha). I'd recon Silja's scar is just like Torben's eye.. Some accident. Hannah becomes quite emotional when she sees Jonas, she's not putting up an act. The other Hannah doesn't know of a Jonas. If this were an alternate Hannah, her emotions are misplaced.